# Select customer who don't have data on sub tables

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I am having customer data table is as below:

[image]

And also sub data table is as below:

[image]

Now i m trying out to access the data which is not available in sub data table

**For example**

**I want customer as per below conditions**

**1) today's date should be within the customer expiry date minus(-) 2 months which means access customer which is gonna expire in two months from today date**

**2) customer should be a member and not a admin**

**3) today system haven't sent a notification to particular customer**

**4) Notification type should be "6"**

So as per above test data

if today date is **2018-01-09** then result should be

First Customer **"Jiren"** system already sent notification

First Customer **"Lee"** system already sent notification

So I want customer id 3 and 4 in result

I have used following query but it is not working properly:

```
SELECT customer_id,customer_token,customer_name,expiry_date
,DATE_FORMAT(`expiry_date` - INTERVAL '2' MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d') AS 
ExpireLim,notification_id FROM customer
LEFT JOIN notification ON customer.customer_id = notification.no_customer_id 
WHERE customer_token != '' AND no_type = '6' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(no_date,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-01-09' 
AND customer_token != 'device_token' AND is_member = 1 
AND CURRENT_DATE = `expiry_date` - INTERVAL '2' MONTH 
AND is_admin = 0
```

Comment: I don't understand how point 3 and 4 work together. You say there shall be no notification for the customer today. And you say the notification type shall be 6. Which notification's type shall be 6? The non-existing one's? Or are you trying to say: "3) today system haven't sent a notification of type 6 to particular customer"?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner "3) today system haven't sent a notification of type 6 to particular customer"?  is correct  ... access the only customer who is eligible  for today list and system havent sent a type 6 notificaion to them

Answer (score 1):

Don't join. If you want to know whether a notification exists, use an `EXISTS` or `IN` clause.

```
SELECT 
  customer_id,
  customer_token,
  customer_name,
  expiry_date,
  DATE_FORMAT(EXPIRY_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d') as expirelim
FROM customer c
WHERE customer_token != ''
AND expiry_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 2 MONTH 
AND is_member = 1
AND is_admin = 0
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM notification n
  WHERE n.customer_id = c.customer_id
  AND n.no_type = 6
  AND date(n.no_date) = date '2018-01-09'
);
```

I suppose that `notification.customer_id` cannot be null. So you can use the simpler `NOT IN` instead of `NOT EXISTS`:

```
AND customer_id NOT IN
(
  SELECT customer_id
  FROM notification
  WHERE no_type = 6
  AND date(no_date) = date '2018-01-09'
);
```

You may have to adjust the expiry clause. I took it to mean what expires from now to now + 2 months. This includes the time. Maybe you'd rather want `date(expiry_date)`. Month lengths are not a precise thing by the way; from February 1 to March 1 is a shorter time than from March 1 to April 1. Maybe you want to make this rule 60 days or the like instead.

Comment: A join must be done inorder to fetch `notification_id `.

Comment: @cdaiga: You are right. It makes no sense to select a notification ID.